# Request Body Missing in Spring while updating using PATCH API in react js

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

Spring shows - **Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.cg.bookstore.entities.OrderDetails com.cg.bookstore.controller.OrderDetailsController.updateDeliveryStatus(int,java.lang.String)]**

Console shows  - **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400**

```
class UpdateOrder extends Component {

state = {
        deliveryStatus:""
 }

handleChange = (event) => {
    const deliveryStatus = { ...this.state.deliveryStatus };
    this.setState({ deliveryStatus: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // Prevents default behaviour of submit button
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.deliveryStatus)
    console.log()
  
    OrderService.updateDeliveryStatus(this.props.match.params.orderDetailsId,this.state.deliveryStatus)
    .then((res) => {
      this.props.history.push("/admin/orders");
    });
  };
```

In OrderService I call the updateDeliveryStatus

```
async updateDeliveryStatus(orderId,deliveryStatus){
    return await axios.patch(BASE_URL+"/"+orderId,deliveryStatus)
    
}
```

The updateDeliveryStatus service in spring

```
@Override
public OrderDetails updateDeliveryStatus(int orderId, String deliveryStatus)
{
    Optional<OrderDetails> opt = orderDetailsRepo.findById(orderId);
    OrderDetails od;
    if (opt.isPresent())
    {
        od = opt.get();
        od.setDeliveryStatus(deliveryStatus);
        orderDetailsRepo.save(od);
    } else
    {
    
        throw new OrderDetailsNotFoundException("Order is not found");
    }
    return od;
}
```

While I was testing backend in POSTMAN , I pass the input as plain string and it works fine. Is it because the input in not in form of json the issue? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when using @PutMethod and wanting to update a resource you need to provide both ID of the resource you want to update and the new body, which in this case I presume is 'OrderDetails', error suggests is missing there.
Without java controller code it's only assumptions though.

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to ask for details.